# Cookie is Null in Other Class

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Method to set user cookie, in UserRest class

```
@Component
@Path("/user")
public class UserRest{
    .............

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(@FormParam("username") String username,
    @FormParam("password") String password){
        return Response.ok(messageDto)
           cookie(new NewCookie("tokenId", "12345", "/medinetra/rest_service/", "192.168.1.2", "", 1800, true))
           .build();
   }
```

It successful when i try to get cookie in UserRest class

```
@GET
@Path("getcookie")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCookie(@CookieParam("token") String token){
    System.out.println(token); //=> write 123456
    return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
}
```

But it will return null when i put getCookie method in CustomerRest.

It also not working when i try the other manner to set cookie.

```
Response.ok(messageDto)
    .header("Set-Cookie", "token="+token+";Domain=192.168.1.2;Path=appname/rest_service;")
   .build();
```

How can i handle this, how to get cookie from the other class.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you aren't specifying a path.  With HTTP cookies if you don't specify a path then it defaults to the path of the resource that returned the cookie.  You should use one of the `NewCookie` constructors that takes more arguments and supply the path.

In the second example you are naming your cookie `tokenId` and not `token` as in the first example.  If your `CustomerRest` code looks like your `UserRest` code then you are asking for the cookie named `token` and not `tokenId`.

Comment: Sorry, actually it is still not work. I have updated my code above.

Comment: This is my url example http://192.168.1.2:8080/appname/rest_service/patient/getdoctorpatient